# Android, Add many button with timer

Tags: android, arrays, layout, button, timer

**i want to make a simple game ..
i have a timer, in every second i add a new button to main.xml
the button always move down
and if i click the specific button, it will be deleted**

please help me ..what i must to do? using array button? help .. i just a newbie
i know u can solve this just in a minutes .. =(

ex

```
b[indek] = new Button(context)        
       layout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.main, null);
       b[indek].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        indek++;
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the instance of layout use

```
 LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

   In your xml file, main xml layout android:id="@+id/layout"
```

and to add a new button to this layout use `layout.addView( b[indek] )`
have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ScrollView2.html) example

Comment: can u be more specific? please help me to code those question .. =( im just a beginner

Comment: @AlvinChristian To add a button dynamically, you will first have get the reference of the layout which you can do by findViewById(R.id.layout), where layout is the id of the your main layout where you want to add the button.After doing this u need to create a button dynamically and add it to the layout using layout.addView()

Comment: can u do this for me? im very-very beginner here but i have this task to do .. i cant make timer, i dont know about layout .. =(

Comment: @AlvinChristian you will have to read about Layout yourself.here is a good tutorial on Layouts http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/